# Excel comparing multiple cells with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need help here with Excel VBA.

I want to know how to compare multiple cells in the same row, but in different columns.

I need to compare something like specific cells E3, G3, I3 and find out if any of it are duplicates and remove the duplicate of whichever was put in first.

Note: A drag and drop function is used to fill in the data.

[image: Image of Spreadsheet]

I tried using something like this

```
Dim R1, R2, R3 As Range 
Set R1 = Range("E3")
Set R2 = Range("G3")
Set R3 = Range("I3")

If (R1 = R2 Or R1 = R3) Then 
MsgBox "Room Already Used!" 
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .Undo
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
End If
```

But I need to compare even more rows and columns.

Answer (score 3):

First things first.

```
Dim R1, R2, R3 As Range
```

You can do this in VB.Net and all three will be declared as a `Range` but in VBA, you have to explicitly declare them as `Range` else the first two will be declared as a `Variant`

```
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range
```

To compare multiple rows and columns you can use a loop. For example

```
With Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet
    For i = 3 To 8 '<~~ You actual row numbers
        If .Range("E" & i).Value = .Range("G" & i).Value Or _
           .Range("E" & i).Value = .Range("I" & i).Value Then
            '~~> do something
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Also instead of *Drag & Drop*, I would recommend using a *Data Validation List* so that you do not have to use `.Undo`. You can simply clear the contents of the cell.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked out if it is not drag and drop, but the client wants the worksheet to be a drag and drop type.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA here. Set a custom data validation rule for cell E3 with the following formula:

```
=OR(ISBLANK(E3),COUNTIF($E3:$I3,E3)=1)
```

Then copy the cell to G3 and I3, and copy row 3 down as far as you need.  You could then set a custom error message using the Data Validation wizard.

The above formula assumes that you only need to check values across the same row (as you state).